# vim local iabbrev

Tags: vim

In Vim I make local buffer definition with `setl` and with `iabbrev` abbreviations. How can I set local buffer or filetype `iabbrev`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:autocmd FileType javascript iabbrev <buffer> abbreviation expanded_abbreviation
```

Is this what you were looking for? It will set an abbreviation for insert mode, that will work only when javascript filetype is open. It will not work in other filetypes nor in other buffers.

Comment: but, if I have open a c file and open a js file, the js file load the iabbrev, this iabbrev affect c file ?

Comment: @juanpablo - For variations on the theme play with the filetype and the <buffer> option (throw it out if necessary). If neither works the way you expect, throw a little description in here, and i'll do my best to help.

Comment: thanks <buffer> is the key, I added you answer to my [tex/vim template](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/templates/tex.snippets.vim#L10)  ;)

Comment: @juanpablo - Glad it helped :)